# How do you get the user info in an Azure API management gateway?

Tags: azure, api, azure-api-management

I am setting up an Azure API management gateway that will be secured by a Azure B2C tenant. I want the API to hit a backend API, get a json response which has an email field and filter the results to only show records that match the current B2C user who has hit the front API.
Tl:Dr B2C User -> Azure API -> Backend API -> Filter Results by B2C email -> return filtered results.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to get the user email from claims on Azure API and forward it to backend API.
Here is the good example: http://devjourney.com/2017/03/23/extract-jwt-claims-in-azure-api-management-policy/